# Добрый день! как менять 2 svg картинки в div по клику.Проблема в том что div с одним классом повторяется

Tags: javascript, массивы, переменные

```
`https://codepen.io/Colonn/pen/OJwryLx`    ссылка на кодипен с примером.
```

существует несколько карточек в которых есть кнопки с одним class="podcasts-img", по клику на див должна меняться одна картинка на другую, в одном месте.

Когда кнопка одна то нет проблем. Когда кнопок много нужна  работа с массивом данных и здесь у меня не получается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы забыли передать аргумент в `forEach`. И уже на конкретный item
необходимо вешать слушатель. А в самом слушателе не надо перебирать все элементы с классом, если вы хотите менять только в данной кнопке. Вы можете обратиться к картинке именно этой кнопки через `this`

```
const img = document.querySelectorAll('.podcasts-img')

img.forEach(function (item) {
  item.addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.querySelector('.podcasts-pause').classList.toggle("svg-pause-active")
    this.querySelector('.podcasts-play').classList.toggle("svg-play-false") 
  })
})
```

P.S. Если очень захотеть, можно только один класс у родителя "тоглить", чтобы картинка менялась.
P.P.S. А если очень очень захотеть, то можно через "делегирование событий" сделать, особенно если элементы будут динамические.

Comment: Pavel Nazarian так изящно и просто спасибо большое)